# Generating query result in for loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, for-loop

I want to generate a query inside of for loop, but I only get the first unique id. How can I solve this?

views

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($id); $i++) { 
    $id = $id[$i];
    $row = $get_cash_card->by_id($id);
    echo $row[0]['id'] . "<br/>";
}
```

model:

```
    public function by_id($id)
    {
        $query = $query = $this->db->get_where('cash_cards_info', array('id' => $id));
        $rows  = $query->num_rows();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

controllers:

```
    public function cash_cards_on_hand_step1()
    {

            $this->load->model('cash_cards');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('id', 'Cash Card', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

            $data['get_cash_card'] = $this->cash_cards;
            $data['id'] = $this->input->post('id');
            $data['main_content']  = 'cash_cards_on_hand_step1';

            $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
    }
```

It runs in 1 unique ID. Any ideas?

Comment: Modify $id = $id[$i]; to $currentid = $id[$i];

Answer (score 0):

You're modifying your `$id` variable inside your `for` loop.  Rather than do

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($id); $i++) { 
    $id = $id[$i];
    $row = $get_cash_card->by_id($id);
    echo $row[0]['id'] . "<br/>";
}
```

You need to do

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($id); $i++) { 
    $newid = $id[$i]; //Change this line
    $row = $get_cash_card->by_id($newid);
    echo $row[0]['id'] . "<br/>";
}
```

Because you are overwriting the value of `$id` on the first iteration it means the `$i < count($id)` part of your `for` loop is no longer true so the loop stops.

Also you shouldn't be accessing your model in the view, that's something you should be doing in the controller

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($id); $i++) { 

    $row = $get_cash_card->by_id($id[$i]);
    echo $row[0]['id'] . "<br/>";
}
```